# How to compare JSON arrays and assign a fixed values

Tags: javascript, json, replace, insert-update, lodash

I want to change all of the favorite values in 'apps' to false except for those that are in the 'favoriteList'.  I would prefer to do this in lo-dash.

```js
var apps = [{
    app_ID: 1,
    favorite: false
  },{
    app_ID: 2,
    favorite: false
  },{
    app_ID: 3,
    favorite: false
  },{
    app_ID: 4,
    favorite: false
  },{
    app_ID: 5,
    favorite: true
  }]


var favoriteList = [{id: 2},{id: 4}];

var updateFavorites = function(){
    _(apps).forEach(function(app){
      if (_.contains(favoriteList, app.app_ID){
        app.favorite = true;
      }else{
         app.favorite = false;
      }
    })
}

//expected outcome is all apps.app_ID values should be false except app_ID's 2 and 4.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Preferably I would like to know a more efficient way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not well versed in lodash yet, but it seems your code is not far off:

```
var updateFavorites = function(){
    _(apps).forEach(function(app){
        app.favorite = !!_.find(favoriteList, { 'id': app.app_ID }); 
    })
};
```

find returns array or undefined for when there are no results. !! is double negation (with implied casting to boolean). So !!undefined === false, !!['anythingorevennothing'] === true

Comment: all examples are good but extra points to this solution for its conciseness in reducing the number of steps.  Thanks this works great!

Comment: Well, from all this underscore learning I forgot about vanilla JS. Upped your answer

Answer (score 2):

I think better search by array, so I converted favoriteList to array

```
var favoriteList = _.map([{id: 2}, {id: 4}], 'id');

apps = _.forEach(apps, function (el) {
  el.favorite = !!~_.indexOf(favoriteList, el.app_ID);
  // or   
  // el.favorite = _.indexOf(favoriteList, el.app_ID) > -1 ? true : false;
  // this is the same, but more clearly for understanding
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/januke/1/edit?js,console

JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/seach-and-change-property-test